# `PropTypes is not defined` during snapshot testing React component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, snapshot, react-proptypes

**Summary:** I get a `ReferenceError: PropTypes is not defined` error resulting in test suite failure on running a snapshot test on my react component with this command: `jest Idea-test.js -c jest-config.json`.

**What I have checked:**

- I checked if I had a different version for `eslint` (I don't, I have `3.x.x`)
- Commenting the prop type validation from the components gets rid of the error and the tests pass.
- `import` or `require()` PropType in the test file has no effect.

**The component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Module, ModuleHeader, ModuleBody } from 'carbon-components-react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Ideas = props =>
  (
    <Module className="ideas">
      <ModuleHeader className="header">
        {`${props.Title}`}
      </ModuleHeader>
      <ModuleBody className="body">
        {`${props.Body}`}
        <a href={props.Link}>
          {`${props.LinkText}`}
        </a>
      </ModuleBody>
    </Module>
  );

Ideas.propTypes = {
  Title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  Body: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  Link: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  LinkText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Ideas;
```

**The snapshot test file:**

```
import 'raf/polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import Ideas from '../../Ideas';
const renderer = require('react-test-renderer');

it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer
      .create(<Ideas
        Title='Title'
        Body='Share your ideas'
        Link='https://shareyouridea.already'
        LinkText='Need ideas now.'
        />
      )
      .toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: My solution to get around this was to use the babel plugin `https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types` to remove prop type validation code from the source files when in test and production environments.

Answer (score 1):

@Ketcomp When you run your application with your `<Ideas />` component, do you get the `ReferenceError: PropTypes is not defined` error as well?

If so, I'm thinking something might have happened when trying to install the `prop-types` package. What does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: No, the application runs fine, the `package.json` has this for the prop-type dependency: `"prop-types": "^15.5.10",` (Re-doing `npm install` doesn't fix things either.)

Answer (score 0):

There have been some changes in `prop-types` from React 15 to 16 - you can see some of it [here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html). Perhaps `carbon-components-react` is calling in the old version/style?

Comment: That is not the case here, I verified that `carbon-components-react` is not indeed using any old convention.